# Azure Set-AzureStorageBlobContent change size block

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-rm

I would like to know how to upload a blob size changing their block size to 100 MB with the command {Set-AzureStorageBlobContent} because I have a problem that I exceed the 50.000 blocks allowed in a blob Storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, It seems you could not do that. The `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent` command essentially calls the [`Put Block`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/put-block) rest api by default, if you want to change the block size to `100 MB`, you need to specific the `Content-Length` in the request header to `104857600` bytes(i.e.100MB).

Per my test, if we catch the request of the powershell command, we could find the `Content-Length` will be `4194304` bytes by default.

In the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/set-azurestorageblobcontent?view=azurermps-6.11.0) of `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent`, you will find a parameter named `-Properties`, it allowed we pass the `CacheControl, ContentDisposition, ContentEncoding, ContentLanguage, ContentMD5, ContentType` properties, they are all the request headers, if `Content-Length` is supported, I think it will be there.

Besides, if you want to improve it, you could post your idea in the [azure feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

[image]

Comment: I think Content-lenght is not supported, I have not found any parameter corresponding to Content-lenght. Thanks you so much anyways!

Comment: Because it's in the right way but it's not a solution, the command don't allow to modify the Content-Length header

Comment: @xavier I think it is enough to be accepted, I answered many questions, some questions ask for if it possible to to do....., if the answer is not possible, they will never be accepted?：-）Maybe it is unreasonable.